# Laravel Auth routing redirects back

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I've created a project and programmed most the content locally until I've got a server. Now I have a server and I moved the files to the server. After I've got the project run normally, I've got in trouble with the authentification. ( I added the authentification on the server, it wasn't there locally ).

Every time I try to login or to register I only get redirected to the login/register route without any error or something like that. The DB connection works fine, I've tried getting some data from it and that worked.

I looked for the auth routes and tried to return the HTTP header data in the register function but the program doesn't reach this function at all.

I also tried to overwrite the register post Route in Router.php in /vendor/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php from:

```
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

to

```
        $this->post('register', 'TestController@test');
```

Just to look if in the @test function in my TestController will be reached, but nothing. Got redirected again.

However, I haven't changed the auth controller etc. at all besides, the redirect route in the login/register-controller

Here are my routes in my web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'web'], function () {
    // my routes - the user shall only see them if they are logged in
});

Auth::routes();
```

If I log a user manually in, everything works fine

I really have no clue what to do anymore, does someone have a clue?

---

php artisan route:list :

[image]

Comment: **I also tried to overwrite the register post Route in Router.php in /vendor/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php from** you should not touch this part.

Comment: if you want a custom `Auth` no isses can make it. but not with `vendor files`

Comment: If you have access to terminal commands try to write `php artisan route:list` and show the auth routes and an example inside the auth group please

Comment: I said "However, I haven't changed the auth controller etc. at all beside the redirect route in the login/register-controller" -- I wanted to say that I mean the redirect routes if the login/registration worked.

Comment: I addet the output of php artisan route:list to my question.

Of course, I know that I shouldn't touch the router.php. I only tried a little test. I would never try to change those files

Comment: @SérgioReis  -- I did :)

Comment: So if you access /login it shows the correct login form. And after log in it returns you to login page if you try to acess any of the others? If you're using layouts , try to go to your master blade view and write `{{Auth::user()}}` somewhere in the page and see there is anything there

Comment: yes, if I access /login I see the login form and if I try to login, I get redirected back to /login. Same with /register - get redirected to /register

Comment: @SérgioReis I tried that and there is nothing. I've also tried -- if(Auth::check()) .... -- but nothing

Comment: Well, I do not know if that is going fix it, but just at least to make sure that we are working in a correct environment. You have mismatched brackets in your _group route_.

Comment: where are them mismachted?

Comment: I will suggest an edit.

Comment: Hi. Please check if the session is being stored.